# How can i remove all the "\" in a python string and replace them with "/"?

Tags: python, string, replace, cwd

I wrote a python script that uses an image from the current folder which is in it and i turned it to `.exe` file so i can run it without clicking on the `.py` file, but if i want to give it to my friends the `cwd`(current working directory) will not be the same so the string which represents mine won't work there so i did this :
[image]

you can't use `\` in python because it's a special character in strings and in my script where i try to replace it with `/`, it doesn't work and all the script in that area becomes green as you can see and i don't know what to do.

Comment: have you tried something like this `filePath= filePath.replace("\\", "/")` ?

Comment: The problem is that a Python raw string literal can't end with a backslash. This is because `\'` is the way you would escape a single quote mark in the middle of the literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple.
Don't do `r'\'` but rather `\\`.
Here's an example:

```
s= r'bruh\bruh\bruh' # this
s = 'bruh\\bruh\\bruh' # or this both work
print(s.replace('\\','/'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As people mentioned you can try with `\\`. for some reasons it deson't work you can also try.

```
import os
strs = "somestring\ok"
strs = strs.replace(os.sep,'/')
print(strs)
```

Gives #

```
somestring/ok
```